# i2d_ASN1_OBJECT issue

Tags: openssl, asn.1

I am trying to encode to DER the ASN1_OBJECT using openssl lib.
There is a function i2d_ASN1_OBJECT that is documented in https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/i2d_X509.html, also I have an example code that does work (for another object type):

```
unsigned char *smder = NULL;
int smderlen, r;
smderlen = i2d_X509_ALGORS(algs, &smder);
if (smderlen <= 0)
    return 0;
```

Where algs is prepopulated STACK OF X509_ALGORs. My code for ASN1_OBJECT:

```
unsigned char *ctder = NULL;
int ctderlen, r;
ASN1_OBJECT* obj = OBJ_txt2obj("1.2.3.4", 1);
ctderlen = i2d_ASN1_OBJECT(obj, &ctder);  // SEGFAULT here
if (ctderlen <= 0)
    return 0;
```

I am getting segfault there.

**UPDATE**

That was a bug and it is fixed now (see: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6914)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual page that you refer to mentions

> If *ppout is NULL memory will be allocated for a buffer and the
>   encoded data written to it.

However, this is not true for the function `i2d_ASN1_OBJECT()` that you use. Check out [the source code of that function in a_object.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2n/crypto/asn1/a_object.c#L67), no allocation anywhere. The segfault happens [here, one level deeper in ASN1_put_object](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2n/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c#L206).

Since it does not allocate memory for you, you will have to provide a buffer yourself, like this:

```
unsigned char ctderarray[64];
unsigned char *ctder = ctderarray;
int ctderlen, r;
ASN1_OBJECT* obj = OBJ_txt2obj("1.2.3.4", 1);
ctderlen = i2d_ASN1_OBJECT(obj, &ctder);
if (ctderlen <= 0) {
    return 0;
} else {
    printf("ctderlen = %d\n", ctderlen);
}
```

which will print the value `5`. Another example of a function that does not do allocation for you is [`i2d_ASN1_BOOLEAN()`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2n/crypto/asn1/asn1.h#L832) and indeed it crashes as well if you try to use it with a `NULL` out pointer.

So why does the documentation contradict your experience and why does it work well for your other code snippet? The documentation is not accurate, but most of the other `i2d_XYZ()` functions are implemented in a generic way, via a (complicated) template scheme, by [the function `asn1_item_flags_i2d()`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2n/crypto/asn1/tasn_enc.c#L101). There, the allocation does visibly happen for you:

```
/*
 * Encode an ASN1 item, this is use by the standard 'i2d' function. 'out'
 * points to a buffer to output the data to. The new i2d has one additional
 * feature. If the output buffer is NULL (i.e. *out == NULL) then a buffer is
 * allocated and populated with the encoding.
 */

static int asn1_item_flags_i2d(ASN1_VALUE *val, unsigned char **out,
                               const ASN1_ITEM *it, int flags)
{
    if (out && !*out) {
        unsigned char *p, *buf;
        int len;
        len = ASN1_item_ex_i2d(&val, NULL, it, -1, flags);
        if (len <= 0)
            return len;
        buf = OPENSSL_malloc(len);
        if (!buf)
            return -1;
        p = buf;
        ASN1_item_ex_i2d(&val, &p, it, -1, flags);
        *out = buf;
        return len;
    }

    return ASN1_item_ex_i2d(&val, out, it, -1, flags);
}
```

which gets invoked (indirectly) by some templatized functions [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2n/crypto/asn1/asn1t.h#L860):

```
# define IMPLEMENT_ASN1_ENCODE_FUNCTIONS_fname(stname, itname, fname) \
        stname *d2i_##fname(stname **a, const unsigned char **in, long len) \
        { \
                return (stname *)ASN1_item_d2i((ASN1_VALUE **)a, in, len, ASN1_ITEM_rptr(itname));\
        } \
        int i2d_##fname(stname *a, unsigned char **out) \
        { \
                return ASN1_item_i2d((ASN1_VALUE *)a, out, ASN1_ITEM_rptr(itname));\
        }
```

As long as the `i2d_XYZ` function you are using is defined via this template-mechanism, (which most of them are) that function will do the allocation for you. Otherwise, you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer - it clarifies a lot. I also asked the openssl team a similar question, and they found a bug in this behavior (and have already [fixed it](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6914)).

Comment: You are welcome, good to know that this has been improved by now. Please don't forget to accept the answer, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).